# "program successfully executed" displayed in the middle of the ASCII graphics that my program shows

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, ascii-art

My aim is to generate a continuous diamond shape. I wrote the code correctly yet I'm having a problem when it runs. The problem is the statement

> "program successfully executed. Press any key to continue"

is displaying in between the shape. How to fix it?

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.code
main proc

Des:


    mov ah,2
    mov bh,0
    mov dh,1
    mov dl,1
    int 10h
    mov cx,7
    mov count,6

    local count:word=vars_room

    Des2a:    
    dec cx  ;moving downward
    mov bl,dl
    mov dl,'1'
    int 21h
    mov dl,bl
    inc dl
    inc dh
    int 10h
    cmp cx,0
    jne Des2a
    mov dh,0
    mov cx,8
    dec count
    cmp count,0
    jne Des2a
    mov dl,'1'
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov bh,0
    mov dh,9
    mov dl,1
    int 10h
    mov count,6
    mov cx,7

    Des2b:
    mov bl,dl
    mov dl,'1'
    int 21h
    mov dl,bl
    inc dl
    dec dh
    int 10h
    dec cx
    jnz Des2b
    mov dh,10
    mov cx,8
    dec count
    cmp count,0
    jne Des2b
    mov dl,'1'
    int 21h

    mov cx,9



    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h`

main endp
end main
```

[i have included an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/679aM.png)

[image: the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using BIOS function `int 10h`, I assume for cursor movement.

You're probably leaving the cursor on a line in the middle of your shape.

After your program exits, the OS prints that text on the line after the one the cursor's on.  **If you don't want that in the middle of your shape, move the cursor to the bottom before you exit.**  (Or print your shape in pure top-to-bottom order so the cursor ends up there, instead of moving it between each character.)

(I didn't read your code in detail, just looked at the image.  But this seems like a good guess.)

Answer (score 1):

The [solution provided by Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643571/program-successfully-executed-in-the-middle-of-the-ascii-graphics-my-program-d/57643609#57643609) could work good enough if the graphic that you show on the screen does not run from top to bottom and left to right.

*If the OS or emulator is hard-wired to only print those messages in the middle of the screen, then it won't help to position the cursor anywhere!*

If your output occupies the whole screen and you want to gaze at it undisturbed, then you could just **postpone ending the program by waiting for an extra keypress**. The annoying message will not appear for as long as that additional key is not pressed.

```
mov ah, 01h    ;Wait for an extra key
int 21h
mov ax, 4C00h  ;Terminate program
int 21h
```